# Scoring in non binary language

Tags: discussion

How would you score a language based off of having 3 voltages 0v 2.5v and 5v AKA not binary but ternary. So how would this be scored?

Comment: @PeterTaylor uhh but this is different from bytes. Bytes are 8 binary bits. I want to use 8 ternary bits

Comment: @Christopher The answer is the same: `Your score is the number of bytes in whatever encoding you pick`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem hmm I feel a new golf lang coming along....

Comment: A binary byte is *not* the same thing as a ternary byte.   If there was actually a submission that operated on a ternary computer (in real life), then  we'd need to decide what to do about that at that point in time.  That said, assuming you could store the ternary program on your binary computer, I'd score it according to the byte size on the binary computer (which would likely be 1.5*ternary_bytes)

Comment: @NathanMerrill interesting. So I did some math that may be wrong BUT the results are 1.25 bytes to ~1.6 bytes per ternary byte

Comment: @Christopher  [One trit is equivalent to about 1.58496 bits of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system)

Comment: "Trit" I have learned a new word. I like that word.